# Anamorphic Cryptography, what do you think about it?

Tags: algorithm-design, authenticated-encryption

I'm currently working on a personal project using a special kind of crypto I've imagined (noooo please don't !!!), called the Anamorphic Cryptography.

**The project**: create a complete keyless cryptographic system with public messaging to exchange data/instructions between machines, where users have no data to keep/protect/hide... or to forget.

**Theoretical basis**: each connected machine (phone, computer, rasp, IOT, ...) got an unique ID made of two 6-digits datas:

1. its position x,y,z in a virtual cube of 100x100x100 points = 1 million, i.e x:25,y:22,z:92
2. a randomized number between 000000 and 999999, i.e 123456.

So the ID of *THIS* machine (called Alice) is 252292+123456. The chances of having two machines with the *same position and number* are close to zero (1/1,000,000,000,000 ?). ID is secretly given when the machine is registered in the project and will always remain the same.

All machines are connected through a public gossip delivering public messages.

When another machine (Bob) wants to send an information or an instruction to Alice, it posts a message encrypted *to be understandable only by Alice* and nobody else: each connected machine can read it but can't use/understand it.

**How it works**: I've defined a 100 chars string including A-Z, a-z, 0-9, + some keyboard signs (+]/-?.) and some diacritic chars (Ö,é,ì,û,ç...). This string is called ALPHA (common language).
ALPHA got a lot of possible permutations (100!): ABC012abc_...  A0CaB2c_b1...  bB1_C2Ab0a...

Creating an anamorphic message is to produce the exact permutation of the recipient: if Bob wants to say `hello` to Alice he'll create the 0-100 table according the 252292nd permutation (Alice's pos) of 0-100 for tens (100! possibilities) and the 123456th (Alice's num) permutation for units (100! more), giving something like

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 00 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 | 07 | 08 | 09 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | ... | 99 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 03 | 28 | 72 | 08 | 12 | 44 | 52 | 30 | 71 | 33 | 41 | 20 | 00 | 19 | 95 | 38 | ... | 62 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

with the second table we now create the DELTA language for Alice:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| A | B | C | D | .... | 0 | 1 | 2 | .... | a | b | c | d | ... | Ö | û | ... | & | _ | / |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| D | 3 | s | V | .... | 5 | ? | n | .... | P | : | 7 | o | ... | g | S | ... | 0 | k | Ç |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`hello` in ALPHA common language is now translated in DELTA[Alice] (i.e `Bs88x`) and sent as is in public gossip. Each machine can of course read this 'Bs88x' message, so each machine, knowing its own ID (pos x,y,z + number) will translate it, creating its own DELTA table.
Chris will understand `Pa//n`, Daniel will undestand `4_ssV`, Emma `BzüüP` ... Only Alice can read `hello`.
As you know, an anamorphose is a way to mask/blur an information to everyone who's not on the right place to understand it. It's the same principle.

I've identified a certain number of problems to solve:

- a brute-force attack is always possible but the attacker has to explore the trillions of possibilities (1 million of points with 1 million of possible machines on each point) to make sure he captures the real one.
- a malicious machine may try a Sibyl attack (Daniel's machine trying to usurpate Alice pos+num)
- a very close machine (in the neighborhood of Alice) may display `hell3` as result, which is easy to understand
- ...

For all these different cases I've tried to imagine some solutions:

- ALPHA is never provided: an algorithm create it dynamically sign-by-sign on request.
- Datas (as ID) are written encrypted in each machine internal storage: every owner can access to its machine ID but they're hard to read. Not impossible but unusefull, knowing your machine ID make sense if your aim is to hack your own account.
- In the gossip, machines don't talk in plain text readable by humans but in a synthetic language made of syntaxical units: exploring all variants never says when the real one was reached. The ALPHA message `TP%Ö3knPç=nA,1á|BZ[;6h;2ì|` translated in DELTA for Alice `ÁtDla2(+92øeÚ2ØTÅ20øeÚrÚ&CG` says `Bob(wallet:100) send 50 to Alice(wallet:20),transaction ref:Ö3knP` ... is brute-forcing the 1 million x 1 million possibilities in 5 seconds - and understanding that only the variant beginning with `TP%Ö3knPç...`is the real one to be executed -  easy to do?
- the order of signs is randomized: a complex regex algo retrieves the right datas order. `BZ[;ob|1%VíOUK=á.5|Alice|0á.5,5á|` and `BoZ[;b|1á.5|Alic%VíOUW=e;0á.5,5á|` (a fictional ALPHA example where Bob and Alice are readable) say exactly the same thing. Is there a way to create an automatic interpretation grid/pattern?
- Because the synthetic language used, a very close pos+num machine won't get the exact string of signs once translated in its own DELTA: required datas are uncompleted and functions can't be executed.
- When such a transaction is launched a protocol verify that Alice and Bob are who they pretend to be: a POI (proof of identity) fingerprint (OS, browser, capacities, ...) is required. A Sybil attack (I'm not Bob's machine but I'm trying to) need to know its pos+num and the exact type of machine Bob is. Sybil possible or not?
- The DELTA[Alice] encryption is produced in Bob's browser before sending message and translation is made by Alice. No MiM attack?
- I've added a optional Vernam reencryption of the message based on the timestamp key, making it readable only 5 seconds by recipient... but will the code be readable for another machine (other pos+num) after 20 seconds, 1 minute, 1 hour?

What I'm now looking for is your opinion as cryptographers on the reliability and resistance of the system. I'm neither a mathematician nor a cryptographer - you guessed it - and I'm struggling with all the different possible approaches and attacks.

If you have any comment or question please use basic english, I'm from France and perfect english is often harder to understand than cryptography :-)

Comment: I'm afraid analysis of a cipher is off-topic here as it does not fill well with the Q&A format of StackExchange and is unlikely to be useful to anyone else. You can find more information about [on-topic question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and the specific issues about [analysing amateur ciphers](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/should-we-allow-questions-about-amateur-ciphers).

Comment: should I delete it ?

Comment: It will likely get closed (unless the rest of the community does not agree with my flag), in which case it does not need to be deleted. I would just like to ask one thing (can't help it): how does Bob know Alice's ID, and how is it kept secret from everyone else?

Comment: by a ZKP based on the angle, distance and elevation (azimuth) of Alice pos 'as seen by Bob'. Bob says something like : "if you are Alice send me the n-digits after the nnth decimals of azimuth". Alice returns a number none else can produce (I guess because cosine is non-bijective)

Comment: But since Bob ends up with the full ID for Alice, Bob will now be able to decrypt anything Carol (or anyone else) wants to send to Alice. This is symmetric encryption where everyone can know the key just by asking to send you a message.

Comment: and the number returned by Alice is of course encrypted with Bob's DELTA to be understandable by other machines.

Comment: no, this would be a Sybil usurp. A machine can't replace its ID by all possibles ID (one millions of millions) to understand message  sended by anyone to anyone. If you can undesrtand it, it's for you. Else you never know who've sent the mess, to whom and its contents.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `DELTA[alice]` is always the same and is computed by the sender of the message. Once I  have computed `DELTA[alice]`, I can decode any other message sent to Alice.

Comment: yes but no. Yes if you can, but you can't. You can't because you are not your machine. All messages to Alice are encrypted for Alice, you (as a machine) can read them IF your pos+num ARE the pos+num of Alice, but they're not. You can of course create a table of translations for ALL machines but you must find the way to change/usurpate ALL IDs in order to make ALL messages readable. To target only Alice your machine ID should be changed with Alice ID, what is hard to perform because you can't know how Alice has encoded its ID during inscription.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question: does Bob's machine compute `DELTA[Alice]` when sending a message to her, and is that all one needs to encrypt/decrypt a message meant for Alice? If so, and if I am Bob, I can just change the program to log `DELTA[Alice]`. If not, then your description is unclear.

Comment: OK I undestand. You focus on a single message as shown in example but it never happens. I can develop this part of complete protocol as an answer (if accepted?)

Comment: You're welcome to edit and clarify your question but I'm afraid it will remain off topic.